# Angular this.router is undefined even declared in the constructor

Tags: angular, undefined, router, angular-routing

As you can see in my angular project I am inyecting the router in the constructor as I have done in several projects that a did a few years ago and i have forget a lot of things, the point is that is not redirecting me to /home and this.router is undefined.
[image]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls:['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor( private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  login(username : string, password: string): void {
    console.log(username);
    console.log(this.router);
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
}
```

[image]

I have seen a lot of post in which the error was that the router was not inyected in the constructor but in my case it is.

Also this is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginBoxComponent } from './components/loginBox/loginbox.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { MainComponent } from './pages/main/main.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginBoxComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { MainComponent } from './pages/main/main.component';

const routes : Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login'}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and the components / pages involved
login.component.html

```
<div class="text-center" style="width: 100%">
    <loginbox [clickLoginFunction]="login"></loginbox>
</div>
```

loginboc.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
  <div id="formContent" >

    <!--
    <div class="fadeIn first">
      <img src="http://danielzawadzki.com/codepen/01/icon.svg" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />
    </div>
    -->
    <div class="m-3">
      <h1>WigStat</h1>
      <form>
        <div class="mt-3">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="emailOrUsername" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="emailOrUsername" placeholder="username">
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3">
          <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="password" placeholder="password">
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3">
          <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth mt-4 mb-4" value="Log In" (click)="loginClick()">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <!--
    <div id="formFooter">
      <a class="underlineHover" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>
    -->

  </div>
</div>
```

loginboc.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'loginbox',
  templateUrl: './loginbox.component.html',
  styleUrls:['./loginbox.component.css']
})
export class LoginBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input()
  clickLoginFunction!: (emailOrUsername: string, password: string) => void;
  
  emailOrUsername!: string;;
  password!: string;

  constructor() {
   }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  loginClick(){
    console.log("Internal function call in component");
    
    if(this.emailOrUsername === undefined || this.emailOrUsername === ''){
      this.showErrorModelInRegister('No se han introducido usuario');
      return;
    } else if (this.password === undefined || this.password === ''){
      this.showErrorModelInRegister('No se ha introducido password');
      return;
    }
    this.clickLoginFunction(this.emailOrUsername, this.password);
  }

  private showErrorModelInRegister(message:string){
    Swal.fire(message);
  }
}
```

console log of "this" vairables
[image]

As you can see in the log I can see that the username is perfectly received

Does anyone knows what is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ddi you defined your routes maybe problem is your routes denfinition.

Comment: How is your `login` method called?

Comment: I think you are trying to pass around `login` as a callback, and you're failing to pass a binding context. So the `this` that is used to invoke the function is probably the `window` global object. Set a `debugger` statement inside the `login` function and inspect `this`, you'll find it's bound to `window`.

Comment: Btw, the "usual" design would be to use an `@Output` property in `LoginBoxComponent`, named something like `submit` and bind to it like `(submit)="login($event.email, $event.password)"`

Comment: A.Chiesa, can you send me some youtube or web link in which I can learn how to do that with @Output and events. my first intention was to do it like this to be able to create a reusable component in other projects in which the login could be different. Thanks. I also edit the post to show you the values of "this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Using an @Output. I was wrong about using an @Input because the info goes from the child to the parent.

loginbox.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'loginbox',
  templateUrl: './loginbox.component.html',
  styleUrls:['./loginbox.component.css']
})
export class LoginBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() clickLoginFunction!: EventEmitter<loginArguments>;
  
  emailOrUsername!: string;;
  password!: string;

  constructor() {
    this.clickLoginFunction = new EventEmitter();
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  loginClick(){
    console.log("Internal function call in component");
    
    if(this.emailOrUsername === undefined || this.emailOrUsername === ''){
      this.showErrorModelInRegister('No se han introducido usuario');
      return;
    } else if (this.password === undefined || this.password === ''){
      this.showErrorModelInRegister('No se ha introducido password');
      return;
    }
    let loginParam:loginArguments={emailOrUsername: this.emailOrUsername, password: this.password}; 
    this.clickLoginFunction.emit(loginParam);
  }

  private showErrorModelInRegister(message:string){
    Swal.fire(message);
  }
}

export interface loginArguments{
  emailOrUsername:string,
  password:string
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { loginArguments } from 'src/app/components/loginBox/loginbox.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls:['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor( private router: Router) { 
    console.log("Contructor of login component called")
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  login(loginParameter : loginArguments): void {
    console.log(loginParameter.emailOrUsername);
    console.log(loginParameter.password);
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
}
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="text-center" style="width: 100%">
    <loginbox (clickLoginFunction)="login($event)"></loginbox>
</div>
```

Thanks @A.Chiesa!

Comment: Yes the solution is to use on @Output, I am a bit novce in angular but I have learn about ir and this is the way! Thanks you so much